# Is fat distributed proportionally around the body?

Tags: nutrition

One guide I have been using to tell me if I really am gaining a lot of weight is a ring around my 2nd last finger on my right hand, if I can slip it on and off without any resistance then I'm fine, however I've been basing this from the notion that if I gain weight it's proportionally distributed around my body, as such, if I get fatter so do my fingers

So I am wondering, is fat distributed proportionally around the body (ie. if your waist gets bigger then your fingers will get bigger along with it)?

Comment: What about simply using scales to track your weight? However, this is of course separate from the fat distribution question (to which I suspect the answer is **no**), but it would save you some trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@fileunderwater's suggestion to use a scale is probably the best answer you could get, but looking at this broadly, the answer is no.  The oft-referenced [apple and pear shapes](http://www.webmd.com/a-to-z-guides/body-fat-distribution) are indeed [very real](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7628000) and have [medical consequences](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2585758/).  One of the issues is that there are [sex differences](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2908522/) in fat distribution.  There is no evidence I can find that finger fat is a good correlate of overall body fat, although admittedly yours could be.  It is also likely a function of how much overweight you were when you began the "experiment" i.e. the relationship probably isn't linear.

That being said, in men the [ratio of the *length* of the second and fourth digits](http://www.nature.com/ijo/journal/v30/n4/full/0803154a.html) are otherwise meaningful.